# Create task automatically when creating bug in Azure Devops Server

Tags: azure-devops-server

We are using Azure Devops Server. When a bug is created, I would like to create a child task automatically. The task does not need to have any particular properties, it just need to be created with default values and have a default name like "Placeholder" or something like that.

I have already encountered some different ways of doing it, but neither of them seems to be well suited for me:

- The extension 1-click-child-links could be used to create a child task by clicking a button in the context menu **after** creating the bug. This will of course work, but it would be even better if it could be done in the background ensuring the task to be created even if the user forgets to click the button.
- As I understand it, using the Microsoft Flow software tasks can be created in the background when creating a bug which would be exactly what I'm looking for, but it would be nice to find a simpler way of doing it without installing a complete software tool.
- I've learned that it is possible to hook into different events by using service hooks (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops). There are a couple of standard integrations, but neither of them can be used to solve my case. So using this method, I guess I need to develop a custom service creating the task?

Is there a simpler solution to achieve my gool or do I need to stick with one of the solutions above?

Comment: Not get your latest information. Just want to check whether below answer is helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: When reading about Logic app I stumbled on this sentance:
"Logic apps deploy and run in the cloud on Azure". So I think this is not a solution for me as our Devops Server is not accessible from outside our company network. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is no built- in TFS connector in logic app.  1-Click Child-Links may be a good choice, although it cannot be fully automated.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround , we can set Azure [Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-first-logic-app-workflow), select `When a work item is created`"as  trigger, and then select `Create a work item` as action.

[image]

[image]

Make sure to set the **Link URL** to the **“When a work item is created” URL** and set the **Link Type** to **Hierarchy-reverse** to create the Task as a child of the Bug item. Please refer to the settings below:

[image]

[image]

Save the Logic Apps Designer, and then when the bug item is created, the child task named Placeholder will be automatically created.